# Error "Could not find a part of the path" while publishing .NET Core Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, publish

I have a very simple .NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework) created with Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 that builds without errors.

I can publish on file system with x64 profile. However when trying to publish with target runtime "win7-x86" gives de following error:

> Could not find a part of the path 'c:\Users\Developer\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2015\Projects\SelfHostTest\src\SelfHostTest\bin\Release\net452\win7-x86\SelfHostTest.exe'

I use a Windows 8.1 x64 machine. I went to "Configuration Manager" and changed "Platform" from "Any CPU" to "x86" but didn't work.

I noticed there's a folder "src\SelfHost2\bin\Debug\net452\win7-x64" but nothing I do creates a structure for x86.

This publish works:

[image]

This publish does not work:

[image]

Here's my project.json in order to help someone helps me.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.WebListener": "0.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net452": {
      "dependencies": {
      }
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimes": {
    "win7-x64": {},
    "win7-x86": {}
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },

  "commands": {
    "http": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a bug in tooling. It will always build for the default RID (and AFAIK there is no way to change it) but then in the publish dialog you see all the RIDs from the project.json and if you select a non-default one publishing will fail since the project was not build for this RID. Try building from command line using the RID you want to publish. This way when you are publishing VS will be able to find binaries and publish should work.

Comment: Ok. I wrote on my developing machine's console "dotnet publish --configuration Release --runtime win7-x86". It created a folder "Release\net452\win7-x86". I copied the content to my windows7. I ran the exe, and I got the error complaining about x86/x64

Comment: Try adding `"platform": "x86"` to your `buildOptions` in your project.json when building for x86

Comment: That worked! But let me ask: when publish to x64 will it really be x64?

Comment: As per https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/04f40f906dce2678d80fb9787e68de76ee6bf57e/src/dotnet/commands/dotnet-compile/ManagedCompiler.cs#L90-L91 - by default the `/platform` passed to the compiler will be `x64`. Setting to `x86` causes to pass `anycpu32bitpreferred`. More details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zekwfyz4.aspx